# How to detect the end of a read or write to a channel

Tags: netty

I'm working on a load balancer, and I'm trying to adapt the basic [example](https://github.com/netty/netty/tree/master/example/src/main/java/io/netty/example/proxy) of a proxy from the Netty source as my starting point.

The change I'm trying to make to the example and having difficulty with is how to detect the end of a request, or response.

I don't want to pin a client to a specific server for the lifetime of it's connection, I want to distribute each request to, potentially, a different server.  But it seems like that is not possible because it's not clear how to tell if the request/response is done.

Since requests can be broken up over multiple reads, I can't dispatch the payload of each read to a different server for obvious reasons.  The same goes for the response back from the server, I don't know when it's done, so I don't know when I can release the link between the client and that specific server.

If I never send a large request or response such that they're never more than one single read or write, my code works exactly as designed, but once they're broken into several messages, I start to have problems.

I had hoped I could use active/inactive or register/unregister events, but since the client will keep the connection open for subsequent interactions, that doesn't seem to be an option.

Also, the balancer is working over multi-protocol request/response cycles, so I can't just inspect for a LastHttpContent message as the indicator that the stream is done.

Comment: is it safe to assume that if i call read on a channel, and i get a `channelReadComplete` without a corresponding `channelRead` that there is no more data to read?  IE, adding a `channelReadComplete` to `HexDumpProxyBackendHandler`, when `ctx.channel().read()` is called from within the listener, if the next event is `channelReadComplete` and not `channelRead`, am I done?

Comment: The answer is no, that's just a quirk of the usage pattern.  It seems this is not possible given simply a sequence of `ByteBuf` objects